# Python while loop continues beyond the while condition

Tags: python, date, while-loop

My while loop doesn't stop when it's supposed to. Obviously there's something fundamental I'm missing here.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
period = 5
start = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
end_final = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-31')
sd = start
while start < end_final:
    ed = sd + datetime.timedelta(period)
    print('This is the start of a chunk')
    print(sd)
    print(ed)
    print('This is the end of a chunk')
    print('+*************************')
    sd = ed + datetime.timedelta(2)
```

which prints dates until the 10th of April 2262 and then gives me the error:

```
 OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

But the while loop should stop at the end of January 2022. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you intend `start < end_final` to become false?

Comment: neither `start` nor `end_final` are changing, so that statement is always true

Comment: Possibly you wanted `while sd < end_final`?

Comment: You changed `sd` instead of `start` so you only change the copied value stored as `sd` not `start` thus your while loop checks the same condition on every iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing `sd` variable but checking the `start`, try:

```py
sd = start
while sd < end_final:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're in a "while loop" you must add a stop indicator, like a flag, condition, or break statement.

here's an idea to break the looping close to january 2022.

```
period = 5
start = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
end_final = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-31')
sd = start
flag = True
while flag:
    ed = sd + datetime.timedelta(period)
    print('This is the start of a chunk')
    print(sd)
    print(ed)
    print('This is the end of a chunk')
    print('+*************************')
    sd = ed + datetime.timedelta(2)
    if sd >= end_final:
        flag = False
```

However, the ending date it's not 31/january/2022, because you're adding the period = 5, so in that case try with "if" statements.